# Why do you need reputation to access meta?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

Why is participating in meta a privilege in Stack Overflow?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta

Comment: This is literally answered on the help page you linked. If you have any specific issue with the explanation there, please adapt your question accordingly.

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate of [Why are meta communities restricted by reputation per community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280224/why-are-meta-communities-restricted-by-reputation-per-community) but it is not a duplicate of that question. That question is asking why 5 rep on one site doesn't allow you into all metas on all sites. This is asking why 5 rep is required at all.

Comment: Getting 5 reputation isn't exactly a major impediment to participation - you can get that with two accepted edits. You can also get more than that with a single upvote on any of your posts (10 points) or an accepted answer (15 points).

Comment: Note that if you get the Association Bonus, you will unlock access to *all* Metas.

Answer (score 8):

Right at the bottom of the [Participate in meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) privilege description you've linked:

> Because we allow anonymous participation, we require a small bit of parent site reputation to prevent spam, and ensure that meta is for active, engaged members of the community.