# What's up with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, hot-questions

Someone seems to be playing with the Stackexchange Hot Question algorithm:

https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/%E8%BF%99%E6%98%AF%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%AA%E4%B8%93%E9%97%A8%E5%88%9B%E5%BB%BA%E7%9A%84%E7%A4%BE%E5%8C%BAwiki%E9%9B%86%E5%AD%A6%E4%B9%A0%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E6%99%AE%E9%80%9A%E8%AF%9D%E7%9A%84%E8%B5%84%E6%BA%90%EF%BC%8C%E5%AE%83%E5%B7%B2%E7%BB%8F%E6%89%B9%E5%87%86%E7%94%B1%E7%A4%BE%E5%8C%BA%E6%9C%AC%E8%BA%AB

This question seems to be the coordinated work of about a dozen entirely new users (created today) to post a "question" that gets a high "hotness" score.

I don't know any Chinese and Google Translate is imperfect, but it seems to be entirely content-free (having only meta-content) and *should* only exist on their meta site (if there is a reason for it to exist at all).

The fact that all participating users seem to be entirely new and are up-voting is rather strange as well (and borders on cheating, in my book).

Comment: http://meta.chinese.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was going to downvote for being in Chinese, but then I took a look at the site title.

Comment: I thought there was a filter that removed mostly non-english titles from the hot questions list?

Comment: Since it's currently #1 on the [hot questions list](https://stackexchange.com/questions) I think this doesn't just concern http://meta.chinese.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: oh... I just saw [this](http://i.imgur.com/zyi565Z.png) :O

Comment: I would reject the Google translation as an obvious audit in the suggestion queue.

Comment: The Chinese on that question does not seem like it's written by a native speaker, AFAICT. It's understandable, but weird. Maybe someone used Google translate.

Comment: Too bad downvotes require at least 125 rep, and the association bonus is only 100

Comment: Sock puppet ring, it's one evil troll against all the might of Stack Exchange. Will be dealt with soon enough.

Comment: This is probably [sock puppets again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184850/sock-puppet-attack-on-gamedev-stack-exchange-exploits).

Comment: Google Translate: *"Should be clear that the resources will not be written by one user or only by the multiple organ dysfunction syndrome, but by whoever wants to contribute."* ... wat

Comment: It looks like the job worthy of [Flack Overstow](http://quickmediasolutions.com/flack). Perhaps it was created by this?

Comment: I just noticed that [Sparn Tesa](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/4884/sparn-tesa) and [user2915](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/2915/user2915) also has an account over at Christianity... wouldn't be surprised if that's the next target.

Comment: @LBT Actually, no, that was the previous target. The mods and community team are aware of this situation. Please spam flag that post on Chinese.

Comment: I spammed a few spam-flags.

Comment: Personally, I don't think it's entirely sockpuppets at work here. Putting the post contents through google translate indicates that it's supposed to be a community wiki of resources to learn Chinese, which seems like it should be on-topic for the site.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: yes, at a superficial level it seems this way. But none of the users involved seems to have *any* involvement with the site before and there's no indication that they *know* each other (which would be required for such coordination). And **if** they know each other, then it's certainly vote-fraud as they're just upvoting each other.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I'm not a Chinese expert, but I know from experience that I have several people who's answers I upvote regularly, *because they make good content*. At what point do you 'know someone', and commit vote fraud, if the content itself is good?

Comment: Ignoring for a second that Google Translate probably messed up, but an "answer" that is only "Including websites, do not post pictures, they will take too much space. Resources in alphabetical order, so they are easier to find. :)" is not worth 12 upvotes.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII No, believe me, there's a bigger game going on here. The same guy pulled a similar trick on Christianity.

Comment: Well I just joined, cast a Spam vote on the question, and the entire question went away.  So either it got the spam-hammer, or another moderator happened to delete it at the exact same time.

Comment: @LBT yeah, currently I can't arouse a comm team member but we did solicit spam flags. Keep an eye out for such posts in the multicollider and on other sites.

Comment: ["Excel Brit" has an account](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/14272/excel-brit) on [skeptics.se].

Comment: There are also [four of them](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers&sort=creationdate) created on RPG as well.

Comment: @JoachimSauer there are more to nuke there. [1](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/2914)
[2](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/2915)
[3](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/2916)
[4](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/2917)
[5](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/2919)
[6](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/2920)
[7](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/2921)
[8](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/2922)
[9](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/2923)
[10](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/2925)
[11](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/2926)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is from a known individual that has been trying (without luck) to cause disruptions all over the network. We're aware of it, tracking it and working with the moderators all over the network to mitigate it.

There's always the person playing chess in the park that decides it's more fun to throw the pieces around instead. This is .. well, that sort of situation. Unfortunate, but much more of a waste of their time than our own.

And it was a full moon last night. Pretty sure that has *something* to do with it.

Comment: I would say he succeeded to cause disruption, even if just for couple of hours. Anyway, why not nuke all 12 accounts he created?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It really only takes a few clicks to get rid of them, and I check every hour or two to see (unless pinged in the interim) and now that folks know what's up - it's really not that disruptive, no? :)

Comment: It is proven that the weirdest behavior happens in the two weeks prior to and the two weeks following a full moon.

Comment: Random thought: Why is it that when an *individual* wants to create problems for Stack Exchange, it takes *multiple people* on our side to mitigate it?  It seems backwards, and yet, this is what happens most of the time.  Something's not right here.

Comment: @casperOne only takes one guy to commit a crime, but dozens to bring him to justice

Comment: @casperOne isn't that how the world works? All systems involving people go on the assumption that most individuals are too scared of justice to do anything untoward.

Comment: @casperOne - As a counterpoint, in a few minutes I can destroy a network of spammers by myself. On the balance, bad actors seem to waste more of their time than ours. Think of how much effort this guy has put into his vendetta.

Comment: "fool moon" at collider seem to happen [every month or two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99077/dont-let-questions-stick-to-the-top-of-the-hot-questions-list-forever#comment483061_101857), this one is just a tad "fooler" than usual _"hundred year floods"_. And easier to get rid of...

Comment: @casperOne I'm working on it - yeah, it's backwards quite often.

Answer (score 5):

It's been deleted now from spam flags. The same trick had been pulled on Christianity (where, since it was in English, it was obvious crap).

If you notice this happening elsewhere, please ping a mod or a community team member and try to get rid of it.

With any luck there'll be an official answer on this soon.

Comment: We were able to delete the question with spam flags.  Just out of morbid curiosity, what's to stop the spam ring from going malicious and doing the same thing (i.e. deleting random questions with spam flags)?  <shudder>

Comment: @LBT You're actually quite close to reality here. Fortunately, mods can reverse all that. Just that it's better to get rid of them before they pull a trick like that.

Comment: What about the 12 accounts? Why letting them all live??

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd because none of us have the power to destroy them. No chinese mods online, and no comm team at the moment. Otherwise the whole thing would have been cleared up in a snap.

Comment: Weird, I alerted Tim Post (who has Godhood powers :)) he commented back "Terrafirminated" and deleted both comments, and it appears nothing was done. :(

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Huh. I can't catch him in TL.

Comment: Well, he's active here on Meta now hopefully he meant "I will check this out and deal with the evil troll" in the comment and will come here to update soon.