# Bug on Hot Questions filtering?

Tags: bug, filtering, hot-questions

Looking at the below question:

[Hot Questions, inability to filter sites... and now German questions? Too much "noise"!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93535/hot-questions-inability-to-filter-sites-and-now-german-questions-too-much)

The proposed fix that was implemented:

```
Questions without a sufficient amount of English are now not only excluded from the stackexchange.com homepage (that's what you see in the “hot questions” tab of the multicollider), but also from Stack Exchange tweets and SE 2.0 ads.

Currently, the basic criteria for the English threshold* are:
a) The title has 2 or fewer non-English words (ignoring proper nouns)
b) The body is 75% English or more, by length

* only applies to certain sites, like german, judaism, and japanese

We're working on adding a "hot" sort to the filters feature. (Currently, the only sorts are "activity", "newest", and "no answers".) When it's finished, you'll be able to create a filter with all questions from a specific subset of sites, and then select the "hot" sort.
```

Yet looking at my hot questions I get is this:

[image]

Was it simply not turned on for that site or is there a bug regarding it?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185794/whats-up-with-this-question